# Does large angular momentum cause swirly bridges when two black holes merge?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, astrophysics

Attached is an image that shows the bridge formed between two adjacent black holes. It shows three example mergers.

Two non-rotating black holes are shown in the first example merger.

In the case of one rotating black hole, does the bridge form like in the non-rotating case in the second example merger, or does it form a swirly bridge like in the third example merger?

[image]

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you're correct that the connection between the two black holes (BH) should be asymmetric, but how to represent that with a drawing may be bit more complicated (even with a single BH).

A photon (for example) that is co-rotating with a spinning BH (also called a ['Kerr BH'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric)) is more able to escape than a photon anti-rotating with the BH.  This is because of ['frame-dragging'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging), which adds a directional dependence to the spacetime near the BH.  There should be an additional asymmetry induced by the orbital motion of the blackholes (i.e. even if neither of them were spinning) in a very similar way, such that the EH are extended along the arcs of motion.

[This is a (brief) simulation of two black holes coming together showing the distortions to the event horizon surface(s)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr1zDVbSjTM), from [a paper on numerical methods in GR](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3557).

Comment: OK, so if the 'swirly' bridge is the correct bridge, and the bridge ends on the far side of the rotating black hole, then wouldn't that cause a 'repulsion' away from the non-rotating black hole?

Comment: @user3634553 No.  The event horizon (or 'bridge') has no effects on gravity itself, it is a region *showing* the effects of gravity.  There is nothing to cause repulsion anywhere ---- gravity is only attractive.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Perhaps repulsion was a bad word to use. How about... does the event horizon bridge cause attraction toward it, when the bridge ends on the far side of the rotating black hole? It's actually an attraction, I suppose.

Comment: Also, does the bridge for two non-rotating black holes form a catenary shape?

Comment: If the bridge does indeed form a catenary shape, then is the bridge analytically solvable?

Comment: @shawn_halayka I don't think the 'bridge' from even two non-rotating black-holes would be analytically solvable.  But I think 'catenary'-like would be a reasonable expectation for two spinning black holes.  Again, no gravitational influence from the event horizon.